# Magento 1.9 / Mysql - How to add 'shipping carrier(title)' column to shipping grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, grid

I'm gonna add the column in my order -> shipment grid!

I want to bring the "title" on 'sales_flat_shipment_track' table.
And it has also "parent_id" column, means entity_id on sales_flat_shipment!

> sales_flat_shipment_track

[image]

> sales_flat_shipment

[image]

So i need to implement this requirment to **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Shipment_Grid**

What code do i have to insert to 
***protected function _prepareCollection()*** & ***protected function _prepareColumns()*** ?

***I tried :***

```
    protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());                 
    $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_shipment_track', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_shipment_track.parent_id', array('title'));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

    protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
    $shippingmethods = array();
    foreach($methods as $_ccode => $_carrier) {
        if($_methods = $_carrier->getAllowedMethods())  {
            if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_ccode/title"))
                 $_title = $_ccode;
               foreach($_methods as $_mcode => $_method)   {
                $_code = $_ccode . '_' . $_mcode;
                $shippingmethods[$_code]= $_title;
            }
        }
    }

     $this->addColumn('title', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'index' => 'title',
        'options' => $shippingmethods,
        ));

}
```

Please let me know it

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bring your carrier information on grid, follow this instruction. Btw it would change the core file directly. What if you do not want to alter core file, please skip this post and i'll update after making local module.

> Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Shipment_Grid

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_shipment_track', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_shipment_track.parent_id',array('title'))->group('title');

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}


    protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    parent::_prepareColumns();

    $this->removeColumn('created_at');

    /*
    $methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
    $shippingmethods = array();
    foreach($methods as $_ccode => $_carrier) {
        if($_methods = $_carrier->getAllowedMethods())  {
            if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_ccode/title"))
                 $_title = $_ccode;
               foreach($_methods as $_mcode => $_method)   {
                $_code = $_ccode . '_' . $_mcode;
                $shippingmethods[$_code]= $_title;
            }
        }
    }
    */

    $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipment #'),
        'index'     => 'increment_id',
        'type'      => 'text',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Date Shipped'),
        'index'     => 'created_at',
        'type'      => 'datetime',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_increment_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
        'index'     => 'order_increment_id',
        'type'      => 'text',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_created_at', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Date'),
        'index'     => 'order_created_at',
        'type'      => 'datetime',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
        'index' => 'shipping_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('total_qty', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Qty'),
        'index' => 'total_qty',
        'type'  => 'number',
    ));


    $this->addColumn('title', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'title',
    ));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

    return $this;
}
```